# How to model this array using an OpenAPI description?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi

I want to write a API that would respond with an array. My OpenAPI description looks like this:

```yaml
definitions:
  DeviceArray:
    type: array
    items:
      type: string
    example:
      - {"DeviceID": 103609131103,"NetworkName": "nzp-20007-gnd-rt-01","RelativeName": "NZP-20007-GND-RT-01.PST.SYTECNMS.NET","Type": null}
      - {"DeviceID": 105621398103,"NetworkName": "nzp-20007-gnd-as-01","RelativeName": "NZP-20007-GND-AS-01.PST.SYTECNMS.NET","Type": null}
      - {"DeviceID": 122403148102,"NetworkName": null,"RelativeName": "BEAS/U_NTU_001","Type": "NTU"}
      - {"DeviceID": 165002297102,"NetworkName": null,"RelativeName": "BEAS/G_HSNS SDP_001","Type": "Alcatel MSAP"}
      - {"DeviceID": 165002320102,"NetworkName": "10.6.194.126","RelativeName": "BEAS/G_ONEA1424X_001","Type": "OneAccess IAD/Router"}
      - {"DeviceID": 160885080102,"NetworkName": null,"RelativeName": "BEAS/U_CISCO_1921_001","Type": "Cisco Packet Switch"}
```

But the response I get is:

```
[
""
]
```

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "response I get" - the actual response from your API, the rendered model examples, something else? Btw, you are using an old version of the editor, try http://editor.swagger.io.

Answer (score 1):

This is not `type: string` obviously, you need to set the type to `type: object` and either define it directly:

```
type: array
items:
  type: object
  properties:
    DeviceID:
      type: string
    NetWorkName:
      type: string
    RelativeName:
      type: string
```

or reference an object if you have already defined it:

```
type: array
items:
  $ref: '#/yourObjectReference'
```